# Confused about the size of my App?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, xcode4.3, appstore-approval

I'm a bit confused about the size of my App! The folder and all the contents comes out at 25.9MB... After archiving in Xcode it says 'Estimated App Store Size: 49.8MB... Anybody know why this is?

Thanks

Comment: do you have any resources included in you project from outside the projects folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this same as an issue with xcode 4.3, since my app it said that it will be `45.8` and the actual size was `31.5`

Answer (score 4):

Are you compiling for armv6 and armv7 (if you want to support iPhone 3G et. al you are doing this)?

In this case the .xcarchive you submit will contain two binaries, making it twice as large. Based on the sizes you mentioned, this seems very likely.