# Adding Audio file in IOS app increases the App Size more than Audio file size

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer

My IOS App size is 2 MB. I am trying to add one .m4a file whose size is 2.8 MB. But when i archive the App in xcode the estimated app store size for the app increases from 2 MB to 7.7 MB, that is increase of 5.7 MB. But my audio file is just 2.8 MB, so i expect estimated App Store size to increase by around 2.8 MB, not 5.7 MB. Is it normal behaviour, can we ignore this or fix this?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10928706/confused-about-the-size-of-my-app/10928822#10928822

Comment: The estimated app store size is wrong for my app too, just ignore it

Comment: @phix23 , it feels little comfortable to know others are having the same problem:-) thanks, will ignore it if its not a issue.

Comment: @Omar Abdelhaifith, Thanks for the link. It said may be the problem with armv6 settings, but changing it didnt solve the issue.